# python dataframe vector comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a df like this:

```
   | name | age |
   |----|------|
   | Dav | 25   |
   | Las | 50   |
   | Oms | 70   |
```

how to create a new df or matrix based on comparison on the age difference of these people to each other?
the output will like this(the * are just for explaining, does't need to show up) :

```
              |* Dav|* Las |* Oms |
      | *Dav  | 0   |  25 |  45|
      | *Las  | 25  |  0  |  20|
      | *Oms  | 45  |  20 |  0|
```

or like this:

```
  | 25  |  45|
  | 25  |  20|
  | 45  |  20|
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) to compute the all pairs differences:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import sub

# compute all pairs diffs
res = df.set_index('name').T.corr(sub).abs()  # optional df.set_index('name').T.corr(lambda x, y: abs(x - y))

# set diagonal to 0
res.values[(np.arange(res.shape[0]),)*2] = 0

print(res)
```

The expression:

```
df.set_index('name').T
```

creates the following DataFrame:

```
name  Dav  Las  Oms
age    25   50   70
```

The *corr* function sets the diagonal values to 1, from the documentation:

> and returning a float. Note that the returned matrix from corr will
> have 1 along the diagonals and will be symmetric regardless of the
> callable’s behavior.
>
> New in version 0.24.0.

and the function [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub) is just:

```
def sub(a, b):
    "Same as a - b."
    return a - b
```